# How to mirror laptop and external monitor with Cinnamon desktop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, cinnamon, external-monitor

`arandr` allows to arrange monitors relative to each other, but how to mirror the screen content (example use case: presentation with beamer where you want to demonstrate the use of a website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to switch the resolution to the least common multiple and position the screens on top of each other. The result is mirroring.